# Is it possible to remove specific section page number in TOC without losing page numbers for its subsections?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

```
\documentclass[twoside,onecolumn,11pt,reqno, a4paper]{amsart} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\@tocline#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{\relax
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth % then omit
  \else
    \par \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace{#2}%
    \begingroup \hyphenpenalty\@M
    \@ifempty{#4}{%
    \@tempdima\csname r@tocindent\number#1\endcsname\relax
    }{%
    \@tempdima#4\relax
    }%
    \parindent\z@ \leftskip#3\relax \advance\leftskip\@tempdima\relax
    \rightskip\@pnumwidth plus4em \parfillskip-\@pnumwidth
    #5\leavevmode\hskip-\@tempdima
    \ifcase #1
    \or\or \hskip 1em \or \hskip 2em \else \hskip 3em \fi%
    #6\nobreak\relax
    \dotfill\hbox to\@pnumwidth{\@tocpagenum{#7}}\par
    \nobreak
    \endgroup
    \fi}
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document} 
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\setcounter{page}{1} %reset the page counter

\section{Introduction}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsection{Subsection}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{subsub}
\subsubsection{subsub}
\subsubsection{subsub}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}


\appendix

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{thebibliography}{3}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to add/remove page numbers around any sectional unit:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,onecolumn,11pt,reqno, a4paper]{amsart} 
\makeatletter
\def\@tocline#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{\relax
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth % then omit
  \else
    \par \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace{#2}%
    \begingroup \hyphenpenalty\@M
    \@ifempty{#4}{%
    \@tempdima\csname r@tocindent\number#1\endcsname\relax
    }{%
    \@tempdima#4\relax
    }%
    \parindent\z@ \leftskip#3\relax \advance\leftskip\@tempdima\relax
    \rightskip\@pnumwidth plus4em \parfillskip-\@pnumwidth
    #5\leavevmode\hskip-\@tempdima
    \ifcase #1
    \or\or \hskip 1em \or \hskip 2em \else \hskip 3em \fi%
    #6\nobreak\relax
    \dotfill\hbox to\@pnumwidth{\@tocpagenum{#7}}\par
    \nobreak
    \endgroup
    \fi}
\let\olddotfill\dotfill
\newcommand{\@notocpagenum}{% Auxiliary definition
  \let\dotfill\hfill% Remove dot leader
  %\@pnumwidth 0pt% Remove page number box width
  \let\@tocpagenum\@gobble}% Remove page number
\newcommand{\notocpagenum}{% Remove page number from ToC
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\@notocpagenum}}
\newcommand{\@resettocpagenum}{% Auxiliary definition
  \let\dotfill\olddotfill% Restore dot leader
  \def\@tocpagenum##1{\hss{\mdseries ##1}}}% Reset page number box
\newcommand{\resettocpagenum}{% Reset ToC page numbering
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\@resettocpagenum}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

\notocpagenum
\section{Section}
\resettocpagenum

\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{subsub}
\subsubsection{subsub}
\subsubsection{subsub}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}

\begin{thebibliography}{3}
\bibitem{abc}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

You can stop adding page numbers to the ToC with `\notocpagenum` and add them back in using `\resettocpagenum`. You have to wrap them around the specific section's you're after *inside* your document, since the location has to be written to the ToC at the right time.