# How to only show \addcontentsline words in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I need to only show student names in the TOC, via using e.g. \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{name}.   However, there are sections, subsections, and paragraphs, so the sections are being listed.  There are no chapters, however.  Is there a way to kill everything in a TOC except what is added via \addcontentsline{.}{.}{.}?

Since there are no chapters, I tried the following method to kill sections and below, and then hang the contents of \addcontentsline to the chapter environment:

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\tableofcontents
```

and used within the text:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{name}
```

and below is the result (which, did not work):

[image]

Comment: you might find this answer helpful:  [Is it possible to remove specific section page number in TOC without losing page numbers for its subsections?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141057/579).  that method is rather complicated.  an alternative is to use the command `\addtocontents` (instead of `\addcontentsline`) and leave the page number field empty. (you haven't given enough information to be more specific;  look for documentation of the `\addtocontents` command.)

Comment: thanks for the comments.  The suggestion and code below from jfbu below worked out to be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly clear how you intend to use your `\addcontentsline` but you can do something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoc}

\etocsetlevel{student}{6}

\newcommand\studentlist {%
  \begingroup
  \etocsetlevel {student}{-1}%
  \etocsetnexttocdepth {student}%
  \etocsetlevel {part}{0}% make parts invisible
  \etocsetstyle {student}
                {}
                {\noindent\textbf{\etocname}\nobreak\hrulefill page \etocpage\par}
                {}
                {}%
  \etocsettocstyle{\section*{\Large\bfseries List of students}}{}%
  \tableofcontents
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\studentlist

\part {One}

\section {foo}

\addcontentsline {toc}{student}{John Doe}
\addcontentsline {toc}{student}{Andrew Doe}
\addcontentsline {toc}{student}{Emily Doe}


\section {bar}

\addcontentsline {toc}{student}{Hillary Doe}
\addcontentsline {toc}{student}{Chelsea Doe}
\addcontentsline {toc}{student}{Marie Doe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For more info see the [etoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) manual `Arbitrary “Lists Of...”, \etoctoccontentsline`

Comment: Thanks - this worked very nicely - and it looks terrific!

Comment: good ;-) please do read section referred to in etoc manual. Particularly perhaps you want `\etoctoccontentsline{student}{John}` rather than `\addcontentsline{toc}{student}{John}`, in case you use hyperref and do not want the students to appear in the pdf bookmarks.